# Delphi Porting -> D6 to D2007 - DevExpress - TdxDBGridLayoutList

Tags: migration, devexpress, delphi-2007, delphi-11-alexandria, delphi-6

I'm newby on DevExpress and I need an help to understand these component.
Thank you in advance :)

I'm migrating an old Delphi software written in Delphi 6 to Delphi 2007 and than hope to XE.
I've installed all the last DevExpress supported package (1.0.59) but I've noticed that TdxDBGridLayoutList it doesn't exist anymore.
How can I emulate the old behavior of that component and how can I reproduce all data that it contains?

At design time it contains 2 sub layout (LAYOUT_A, LAYOUT_B -> TdxDBGridLayout) each layout contains others components.
LAYOUT_A

- Bands (TdxTreeListBand)
- Columns 10 datas (Date String Int ecc) (TDBGridMaskColumn)
  LAYOUT_B
- Bands (TdxTreeListBand)
- Columns 20 datas (Date String Int ecc) (TDBGridMaskColumn)

One of the layout at the end of the form create is assigned in the code to a TdxDBGrid.
The TdxDBGridLayoutList is placed in the datamodule.
The form is used for 2 function and for each function the Layout is assigned to the same DBGrid.

There is another way to do this?

I've tried to use directly the new TcxGrid in an test form, but I don't know if it is the right way and I think that cause a problem in the form that need to update from TDXGrid to TcxGrid.

Thank you
Gianluca

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress replaced TdxDBGrid and related components with TcxGrid.
TcxGrids in older and newer versions of their controls are generally compatible.

The most reliable way to store different grid views for TcxGrid is to use TcxGridViewRepository.